# how to disable and enable buttons in delphi

Tags: delphi, button

how do you disable and enable buttons in delphi

here is my code

```
procedure Tfrm_color_demo.btn_purpleClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frm_color_demo.color := clpurple;
  frm_color_demo.caption := 'purple';
  #disable btn_purple enable btn_yellow  
end;

procedure Tfrm_color_demo.btn_yellowClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frm_color_demo.color := clyellow;
  frm_color_demo.caption := 'yellow';
#disable btn_yellow  enable btn_purple 
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please find a tutorial. This is extremely basic stuff, and we're not  here to tutor you on those basics. Google can find a tutorial site or book for you to use.

Comment: Delphi IDE includes a lot of help.

In your case, you only had to press F1 key with a focused TButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [**Enabled**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Enabled) property for the control of your choice. For example to disable button:

```
Button1.Enabled := False;
```

to enable:

```
Button1.Enabled := True;
```

Comment: If you don't know what a property is, then perhaps you need to concentrate on learning the language more thoroughly before proceeding further.